# Cannot read bounty text

Tags: support, bounty

On [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44152296/428724) a user started a bounty, and wrote some text to explain why. Only part of the text is visible - how do I see what it says after the ellipses?[image]

Comment: It's a complete sentence; they were probably using it to signify a pause.

Comment: At any rate, there is no 'ellipses feature' in the bounty display box. The whole text is always shown (which is limited in size).

Comment: Oh, so it's not a bug. I hate it when people misuse ellipses[...](http://writing-skills.com/five-annoying-ways-use-ellipsis)

Comment: @AlonEitan Indeed. I can't think of a legit reason to indicate that you're trailing off in a post here.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I think that that is exactly what he wrote, including the 3 dots.